# problems with showdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hello i'm a beginner in angularjs so i try to do a Custom Components project but it's doesn't work please help me.

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>


    </head>
<body>

    <markdown>
        # Hello world
        - list item

    </markdown>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the code of app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('markdown', function () {
        var converter = new showdown.converter();
            return{
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function (scope,element,attrs){
                    var htmlText =converter.makeHtml(element.text());
                    element.html(htmlText)
                }
            }
    })
```

this is what is displayed in the console
   ReferenceError: showdown is not defined

Idon't know why !!!
thank's for your help :)

Comment: You need to inject showdown into the directive... or use $window

Comment: I believe it's `Showdown.converter()` not `showdown.converter()`

Comment: thank's for your reply , can you please more explain.

Comment: Replace `new showdown.converter();` with ` new Showdown.converter()`